# GSON deserialization in java

Tags: android, gson

This is my jsonObject, the response from server:

```
{
status: 0,
msg: "ok",
user_lat: 0,
user_lng: 0,
requested_rows: 30,
returned_rows: 30,
query_id: "",
page_repos: 30,
poi_list: [
{
poi_id: 190,
poi_name: "Ristea Antik ",
poi_disp_address: "Holbergsgade 19, København K, 1057",
poi_lat: 55678607,
poi_lng: 12590144,
poi_icon_url_generic: "/images/190.jpg",
poi_icon_url: "/images/spec/190.jpg",
poi_rating: 2,
user_dist_to_poi: 456
},
{
poi_id: 191,
poi_name: "Galerie Bork",
poi_disp_address: "Store Regnegade 2, København K, 1110",
poi_lat: 55681371,
poi_lng: 12581668,
poi_icon_url_generic: "/images/191.jpg",
poi_icon_url: "/images/spec/191.jpg",
poi_rating: 2,
user_dist_to_poi: 456
},
{
poi_id: 192,
poi_name: "Books & Curiosities",
poi_disp_address: "Læderstræde 9, København K, 1201",
poi_lat: 55678118,
poi_lng: 12578220,
poi_icon_url_generic: "/images/192.jpg",
poi_icon_url: "/images/spec/192.jpg",
poi_rating: 2,
user_dist_to_poi: 456
},
{
poi_id: 193,
poi_name: "Otto Berg Art & Antiques",
poi_disp_address: "Gothersgade 137, København K, 1123",
poi_lat: 55685008,
poi_lng: 12571328,
poi_icon_url_generic: "/images/193.jpg",
poi_icon_url: "/images/spec/193.jpg",
poi_rating: 2,
user_dist_to_poi: 456
}
}
```

---

It will return an object. In JSON object I am having also JSON arrays.

Please help me how to Deserialize that object using GSON.

Comment: Thanks to Lennart and sunil Gupta for Editing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just creata a class:

```
public class Response {
    private status int;
    private String msg;
    private double user_lat;
    ...
    private Poi[] poi_list;
    ...
}

public class Poi {
    private long poi_id;
    private String poi_name;
    ...
}
```

And then you just cal

```
Response response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, Response.class);
```

Comment: But how to access that **poi_list**. I am beginner to GSON and JSON thats why i am asking in much detail..

Comment: You can create getter method in Response class. Something like this: `public Poi[] getPoiList() { return poi_list; }` and then just call `response.getPoiList();`

Comment: Yes i did the same...Thank you so much...